# ERROR 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row?

Tags: mysql

I'm learning SQL, so I test some queries:

```
mysql> select * from users where id = 1 or (select id from users);
```

result:

> ERROR 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row

I found that if I use any `concat` functions like `group_concat`, the error will disappear.

But I need to know why the error happened and I'm just select 1 column ' id ' in the subquery.

Comment: select * from users where id = 1 or (select id from users limit 1);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your example in `(select id from users)` result will be

```
|----|
| id |
|----|
|  1 |
|  2 |
| .. |
|  n |
|----|
```

Error says:

> Subquery returns more than 1 row

as you can see what I mentioned, your subquery returns a lot of rows.

---

As I see in your example. You want to load full user data if it exists, else load id from the first user. Why do not do something like

```sql
select * from users where id = 1 or not id = 1;
```

JQL Fiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ad769e/2